# Input com máscara monetária do plugin jQuery Mask de Igor Escobar

Tags: jquery

Implementei o [plugin jQuery para máscaras](https://github.com/igorescobar) em campos de formulários desenvolvido por Igor Escobar, está funcionando corretamente, mas ocorre que ao digitar valores numéricos de 1 a 99 tirar o foco do campo, valores de 1 a 99 não completa o decimal com ",00", alguma sugestão de implementação dessa possibilidade no código?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' class='money'>
<input type='text' class='money'>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.money').mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', {reverse: true});
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.money').mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', {reverse: true});
});
```

```css
input.money
{
font-size: 12px;
padding: 6px;
min-width: 100px;
color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' class='money'>
<input type='text' class='money'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez não seja a melhor solução, mas a maneira mais fácil de resolver isso agora seria deste método, talvez se procurar melhor na documentação deve conter uma solução para esse problema com algum parâmetro a ser passado

BIBLIOTECA RECOMENDADA: [LINK PARA BAIXAR](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JyW2KjplXYBkIpCiEhCfN9WrLr0KJxeA/view)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.money').mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', {reverse: true});
});
$(".money").focusout(function(){
  if($(this).val().length <= 2){
    temp = $(this).val()
    var newNum = temp + ",00"
    $(this).val(newNum)
  }
})
```

```css
input.money
{
font-size: 12px;
padding: 6px;
min-width: 100px;
color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' class='money'>
```

Comment: oi, procurei na documentação, e minha dúvida e a de outros usuários estão em aberto no github no perfil dele, tem os callbacks mas não está resultando em nada isso.

Comment: Certo, recomendo utilizar outra biblioteca, pois eu passei pelo menos problema nesta biblioteca e o que eu fiz foi mudar, vou ver se encontro a que utilizei e te passo

Comment: Existe um erro aí no código, " if($(".money").val().length <= 2){ ", aí vai pegar todos os campos com a classe e não resulta em nada, teria de ser " if($(this).val().length <= 2){ "

Comment: Obrigado por corrigir!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JyW2KjplXYBkIpCiEhCfN9WrLr0KJxeA/view?usp=sharing 
Aqui está, espero ajudar! Boa sorte

Comment: gratidão, precisava bastante disso.